# Ajax post request login issue

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, xmlhttprequest

We are having a issue when trying to login. Is we send our username and password over a XMLhttprequest as post there parameters do not seem to be send with them and therefor we are unable to login.

The code is as following:
Javascript file

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){   
console.log("click");

     usernm= document.getElementById("username").value;
      passwd= document.getElementById("password").value;


      var send2 = "username=" + usernm + "&password=" + passwd;
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.open('POST' , "myurl.com/login.php",true);
        request.dataType=('jsonp');
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-  urlencoded");


 request.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
 if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
 alert(request.responseText);
 }
 }
 request.send(send2);
```

The login.php is this

```
 require_once 'connect.php';

 session_start();
 $uName = ($_GET['username']);
 $pWord = ($_GET['password']);
 $login = "SELECT Username,Password FROM User WHERE Username = '$uName' and Password='$pWord'";
 $res = mysql_query($login);
 $num_row = mysql_num_rows($res);
 $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($num_row);

 if( $num_row == 1 ) {
  echo "true";


 }
 else {
 echo "false";

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You collapsed both `POST` and `GET` method,

Modify this one,

```
 $uName = ($_POST['username']);
 $pWord = ($_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $uName = ($_POST['username']);
 $pWord = ($_POST['password']);
```